# How to make an Action that opens a page that is filtered after multiple option values in AL?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, dynamics-business-central, microsoft-dynamics-nav, dynamics-al

I'm pretty new to business central so excuse me if this is a rather stupid question. I have been trying to make a button that sends the user to a page where he can see products that are new or old.

A product has a field named "Status" which can have the values "New", "Old", "SoldOut" or "BeingDelivered".

So my question is how do I set the filter to only show products that are either "New" or "Old". I got this so far which only shows products that are "New" but I can't figure out how to show "New" OR "Old" ones.

```
Group(group1)
{
    Action(testAction)
    {
        ApplicationArea = All;
        Caption = 'TestAction';
        RunObject = page Products;
        RunPageLink = Status = const("New");
    }
}
```

I have been trying to find a solution and tried a bunch of different approaches but couldn't figure much out. Any help is really appreciated.

Little Edit:
Here is an example of what I would ideally want which obviously doesnt work though.

```
Group(group1)
{
    Action(testAction)
    {
        ApplicationArea = All;
        Caption = 'TestAction';
        RunObject = page Products;
        RunPageLink = Status = const("New|Old");
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter` instead of `const`

Cheers

Comment: Example https://forum.mibuso.com/discussion/46663/setrange-or-setfilter-on-ore-than-one-field#Comment_228169